# Between in a CFIF statement

Tags: coldfusion, cfml

I am sending a comma delimited list from a formset and each of the possible selected items except the first can only be added if the first is not selected.

QUANTY=**10-1**,1-0,2-0,3-0,4-0,5-0,7-0,6-0,8-0,9-0,15-0,13-0

Each element in the list is a number, a hyphen and another number. The first number is the product number and the second is quantity.

If the first element in the list is 10-1 you cannot add any other items so they would have to be number -0 as in 3-0.

This statement works if any of the other elements contain -1

```
 <cfif ListFirst(QUANTY) IS "10-1" AND ListRest(QUANTY) contains "-1">
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <font color="#FF0000"><strong>
            You cannot add any features to the Basic Plan<p>
            Please click "Back" and reset your order.
            </strong></font>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <cfabort>
    </cfif>
```

The problem arises when a quantity larger than 1 is selected as in:

QUANTY=**10-1**,1-0,2-0,3-0,4-0,5-0,7-0,6-0,**8-4**,9-0,15-0,13-0

I cannot seem to get the "Between" function to work in the part of my cfif statement:

```
 AND ListRest(QUANTY) contains "-1">
```

as in:

```
 AND ListRest(QUANTY) BETWEEN "-1" and "-50">
```

Any suggestions appreciated

Answer (score 3):

```
ListRest(quanty) contains "1"
```

will return true on values such as "1-0".  That's clearly not what you want.

I suggest treating your string as nested lists.  The outer list is comma delimeted and the inner is hyphen delimited.  This approach should work

```
<cfif ListLast(ListFirst, Quanty, ","), "-") gt "0">
loop through the rest of Quanty and use ListLast to check 
the values after the hyphen
<cfelse>
code for this condition
</cfif>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the script above and got an error on the ,...

I wrote this and it seems to work ok:

```
 <cfset qty1 = "#ListFirst(QUANTY)#">
 <cfset qty2 = ListLast(qty1, "-")>
 <cfif (qty2 GT 0) AND  
   ((ListRest(QUANTY) contains "-1") OR 
   (ListRest(QUANTY) contains "-2") OR 
   (ListRest(QUANTY) contains "-3") OR 
   (ListRest(QUANTY) contains "-4") OR 
   (ListRest(QUANTY) contains "-5") OR 
   (ListRest(QUANTY) contains "-6") OR 
   (ListRest(QUANTY) contains "-7") OR 
   (ListRest(QUANTY) contains "-8") OR 
   (ListRest(QUANTY) contains "-9"))>

   do this
 </cfif>
```

Thanks and if there is a shorter way to write it I would appreciate the input.

Comment: Not everyone tests the code they post first. While clearly not meant to be a complete example, obviously their cfif snippet was untested. However, you already know the basic syntax for those functions: `ListFirst(list, delim)` and `ListLast(list, delim)`. Just replace "list" with one of the function calls to nest them.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution should work, but a Regular Expression might be more elegant.

```
<cfif ListFirst(QUANTY) is "10-1" and REFind("-[1-9]",ListRest(QUANTY))>

Do something

</cfif>
```

Should work.  Reg Expressions are really helpful.  If you haven't used them before, the one above looks for a dash followed by a number from 1 to 9.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest just using a regex by itself (no need to do list manipulation to check if a pattern exists):

```
<cfif REFind("^[0-9]+-[1-9].+-[1-9]", QUANTITY)>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <font color="#FF0000"><strong>
            You cannot add any features to the Basic Plan<p>
            Please click "Back" and reset your order.
            </strong></font>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <cfabort>
</cfif>
```

Tested on the following:

```
"10-1,1-0,2-0,3-0,4-0,5-0,7-0,6-0,8-0,9-0,15-0,13-0"  no match (pass)
"10-0,1-5,2-0,3-0,4-0,5-0,7-0,6-0,8-0,9-0,15-0,13-0"  no match

"9-1,1-5,2-0,3-0,4-0,5-0,7-0,6-0,8-0,9-0,15-0,13-0"   match (fail)
"10-1,1-5,2-0,3-0,4-0,5-0,7-0,6-0,8-0,9-0,15-0,13-0"  match
"11-1,1-5,2-0,3-0,4-0,5-0,7-0,6-0,8-0,9-0,15-0,13-0"  match
"10-1,1-0,2-0,3-0,4-0,5-0,7-5,6-0,8-0,9-0,15-0,13-0"  match
```